# TCP 3-Way Handshake Issue: Client not responding with ACK

Tags: networking, tcp

I have a Java application running inside a virtual machine (VM) that uses S3-compatible storage as an object data store. Periodically, the VM is destroyed, re-deployed, and reconfigured. During the initial configuration of the application, I set up its S3 client. Occasionally, this S3 client configuration step fails with HTTP request timeouts. After a few retries, the configuration is successful. We haven't observed any outages with the S3 storage endpoint, so we suspect that the issue may be within our application. To investigate further, we captured a TCP dump from the VM to analyze network packets.

Upon analyzing the TCP requests between the client (the application) and the server (S3 endpoint), we noticed a deviation during the initial TCP 3-way handshake. Specifically, the client initiates a SYN, and the server responds with SYN-ACK. In a typical scenario, the client should reply with an ACK, but instead, it discards the SYN-ACK and initiates a retransmission of SYN after some time. Some sources suggest checking the IP checksum header of the packets, but our analysis indicates that they appear to be correct. I have limited knowledge in networking, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[Wireshark output TCP Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXIxC.png)

Comment: Wireshark would tell you if there was a checksum problem. I suspect a firewall is blocking the response packet.